# Create ready gentoo images for deployment

Tags: deployment

Assume I know exactly what hardware each target machine contains.
Can I have reliable way to prepare images for target machines on my computer, which I can just copy over on that other drive and there she goes?

This has so many uses:
Preparing VMs
Deploying to older computers that need weeks to compile all the stuff...
Deploy to other architectures, like arm and mips for routers, singleboards, phones....

Is there any halfway reliable way for that?

Comment: Have read much stuff, still havent found something that pleases me.